# Setup Exe for NestJS API Application

Tags: typescript, bundle, exe, nestjs

i'm new to typescript and NPM, i have created an API project with [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) node framework. I'm trying to create an EXE file by bundling my application. I have tried [Pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) exe creator, and [fuse-box](https://fuse-box.org/docs/getting-started/setup). Still i could not found any working solution. Please someone help me to  bundle my application into an exe file. I Have attached my package.json in this question.

`

```
{
  "name": "health-first",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Meal management system",
  "author": "Dhayananth",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
    "prestart:prod": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^5.4.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^5.4.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^5.2.2",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "nestjs-flub": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.11",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/testing": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.1",
    "@types/node": "^10.7.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.5",
    "fuse-box": "^3.7.1",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "supertest": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^23.1.3",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.5.0",
    "tslint": "5.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure why you'd want to create an exe file from the application? But then I'm not a windows user. In my opinion and experience I use commander or vorpal to create execution commands using a nest container.

This is an example of a script I use

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { TaskConsumer, JobConsumer, ConsumerModule } from './consumers';
import * as commander from 'commander';
const pack = require('./../package.json');
import { AppModule } from 'app.module';
import { ConsumerInterface } from 'consumers/consumer.interface';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap(requestedConsumer: 'task' | 'job') {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  await app.init();

  const consumer =
    requestedConsumer === 'task'
      ? app.select(ConsumerModule).get<ConsumerInterface>(TaskConsumer)
      : app.select(ConsumerModule).get<ConsumerInterface>(JobConsumer);

  await consumer.listen(requestedConsumer);
}

commander
  .version(pack.version)
  .command('run <consumer>')
  .action((requestedConsumer, cmd) => {
    if (requestedConsumer !== 'task' && requestedConsumer !== 'job') {
      Logger.warn(
        `Consumer [${requestedConsumer}] is not a valid consumer. Please enter 'task' or 'job'`,
        'Command',
      );
      process.exit();
    }

    bootstrap(requestedConsumer);
    process.stdin.resume();
  });

commander.parse(process.argv);
```

I then run this script in dev like so `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/queue.ts run task`. Then in prod `node dist/queue.js run task`. I could add a shebang but... ...I dunno why I didn't to be honest!

Not sure this is what you was after? But this is how I would create a command in which you can execute using nestjs.

Comment: Thanks for you advice. But i found my solution. I created a single js file using webpack, then i have installed “pkg” npm pack. Using this pkg i have created my perfect working exe file that i can run it on windows pc without needing to install node or any dependencies. Thanks to Shady G. Khalifa